# Using list.files correctly in an R script

Tags: r, error-handling, execution

I am writing an R script and using this function

```
filenames <- list.files(opt$bamfolder, pattern = "\\.bam$")
```

but when I run it i am getting this error

```
Error: unexpected input in:
 filenames <- list.files(opt$bamfolder, pattern = "\"
Execution halted
```

Does anyone know what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: try `pattern = "\\.bam$"` or `pattern = "[.]bam$"`.

Comment: I'm not sure why that isn't working for you, but if you are just trying to list all files with the extension `.bam`, `pattern="*.bam"` should work as well.

Comment: What is `opt$bamfolder` ?  That doesn't seem like it would return a file path unless you have a structure with file paths in it.  Check that it's not a factor if it's a data frame column

Comment: @RichardScriven opt$bamfolder is there because I used getopt and set a variable for bamfiles earlier in the script

Comment: The error message is suggesting a weird character, possibly a non-printing one. What editor are you using? Does it allow you to sanitize your inputs?